# Powershell accessing module variable inside function

Tags: powershell, module

Can anyone explain me why I can get data from the xml file if I use this:

```
[xml]$configXml = Get-Content -Path "c:\test.xml"
$configXml.Config.Client.Servers.Server.name

Output: srv1
```

But if I use it inside a module, I get no data at all:

```
[xml]$configXml = Get-Content -Path "c:\test.xml"

function global:XTR_GetXmlConfig{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Option
)

    return $configXml.Config.$Option
}

XTR_GetXmlConfig -Option Client.Servers.Server.name
```

only the first node retrives data using the module:

```
XTR_GetXmlConfig -Option Client
```

My xml is very basic:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Config>
    <Client>
        <Domain>test.pt</Domain>
        <Servers>
            <Server>
                <Name>srv1<Name>
                <IP>192.168.0.1</IP>
            </Server>
            <Server>
                <Name>srv2</Name>
                <IP>192.168.0.2</IP>
            </Server>
            <Server>
                <Name>srv3</Name>
                <IP>192.168.0.3</IP>
            </Server>
        </Servers>
    </Client>
</Config>
```

Comment: I guess because your function is declared in a higher scope (global) than the variable (script).

Comment: i have also tried setting both to global... same behaviour... and I think it is not necessary because I am only accessing the variable xml inside the module

Comment: Line seven "7" of the .xml file needs to have the ending tag start with a `/` character. There should also be a `<` as the first character of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mike Garuccio's answer is right. But, I'm not sure that there needs to be that much work done on the $Option string. Also, I made the top level part of the parameter to keep it out of the function. How about...?

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

[xml]$configXml = Get-Content -Path ".\xmltest.xml"

function global:XTR_GetXmlConfig {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Option
)
    Invoke-Expression "return `$configXml.$option"
}

XTR_GetXmlConfig -Option Config.Client.Servers.Server.name
```

Comment: Yep this is better, I'd already gone down the track of separating out the properties and didn't think to try it with a single string like I should have, upvoted your answer and this is the one that should be accepted.

Comment: @Liturgist I'm still working my way through powershell. Can you explain me why you have used the Param() and [cmdletbinding()] in the top of the module ? I thought the parameters were only used in function... also I intend to use the variable inside the module, that way It will be available to all the functions created in it. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you

Comment: Those extras at the top enable standard switches like -Verbose to be used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that it is trying to treat your entire $option variable as the property to access rather than moving down through the tree (think of it trying to evaluate like below)

`$configXml.Config.'Client.Servers.Server.name'`

```
Theres probably a better way to deal with that but below is what I came up with, basically it builds the command to run from scratch and then invokes it, generated a plain list of server names on my machine.  Hope this helps.

[xml]$configXml = Get-Content -Path "test.xml"

function XTR_GetXmlConfig{
 Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$Option
)
$options = $option.split('.')
[string]$command = 'return $configXml.Config'
foreach($o in $options){
    $command += ".$($o)"
}

Invoke-Expression $command
}

XTR_GetXmlConfig -Option Client.Servers.Server.name
```

Sorry for the formatting, powershell never wants to paste in correctly.